# Proof of observations on natural numbers being expressed as differences of squares.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Inspired by this Hagon Von Eitzen's answer( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591028/789547) I
started investigating how I could express natural numbers as differences of squares.

Using the method explained in the solution,
I investigated natural numbers up to $60$ manually.

I observed the following:

1. There is no way to express numbers of the form $4k+2$ as a difference of two squares.

2.There is one and only one way to express prime numbers
(except $2$) as a difference of two squares.

3. The smallest number that can be expressed as a difference of two squares in two different ways is $15$ and the smallest number that can be expressed as a difference of two squares in three different ways is $45$.

As,

$15= 8^2-7^2=4^2-1^2$.

$45=23^2-22^2=9^2-6^2=7^2-2^2$.

I could prove
point $2$ easily but could not prove point $1$.

Also I am interested in knowing how I could find the smallest natural number that could be expressed as a difference of two squares in four different ways without manual calculation.

Comment: $24 = 5^2-1^2$. I would like to know more about the context of your question, i.e. the post containing Hagon Von Eitzen's answer.

Comment: Sure, I am providing the link to it.

Comment: $5\cdot 7+4=8^2-5^2$

Comment: In fact, $13$ is a prime number and is of the form $5k+4$, so your statement (2) contradicts (1). Note $13=7^2-6^2$. Did you mean numbers of the form $4k+2$?

Comment: A factorization of a number into a product of two unequal odd or two unequal even numbers will yield a solution to the difference of two squares.

Comment: @ Oldboy I made mistake in writing the form , sorry.  meant $4k+2$

Comment: @Stinking Bishop. Yes.

Comment: Every square is in the form of $4k$ or $4k+1$. Therefore their difference cannot be of the form $4k+2$.

Comment: Oh yes, I understood. Thanks for that! Any idea for point $3$?

Comment: Cf. [OEIS: A100073](https://oeis.org/A100073)

Comment: BTW, the fact that $a^2+b^2$ can never be of the form $4k+3$ is *really* important. And on a related note, it can be shown that all primes not of the form $4k+3$ can be written as the sum of two squares in exactly one way.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a natural number $n$ is the difference of two squares $x^2$ and $y^2$. Then
$$n=x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y),$$
so for $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$ we have $n=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers. Conversely, if $n=ab$ for natural numbers $a$ and $b$ then for $x=\tfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $y=\tfrac{a-b}{2}$ we have
$$x^2-y^2=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2=ab=n.$$
Of course $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily integers; they are integers if and only if $a+b$ and $a-b$ are both even. Equivalently, if and only if $a$ and $b$ are both odd, or both even.

So the number of ways we can express a natural number $n$ as a difference of two squares is the same as the number of ways we can factor $n$ as a product of two integers, that are both odd or both even. In particular, this shows that if a number is a difference of two squares, then it is either odd or divisible by $4$, so it cannot be of the form $4k+2$.

Can you use this characterization to find the least natural number that is a difference of two squares in four ways?

Comment: Of course, $a+b\equiv a-b \pmod 2$, but I guess that those new to this topic ought to prove that. ;)

Comment: @Servaes. That is a really nice way to look at it, thanks! Let me think how I could use this characterisation.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 Proof:

$$4k+2=2(2k+1)\ =\ a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Obviouslu LHS is divisible by 2 so $2\mid a-b$ or $2\mid a+b$. It means that $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd. So RHS has two factors divisible by 2 and therefore must be divisible by 4. But the LHS is divisible by 2 only (the other factor of LHS is odd). Contradiction.

Alternative proof: It's easy to check that all squares are either equal to 0 or 1 modulo 4. Their differencies can be 0, 1 or 3 but not 2 (modulo 4)